# Redux Selector - concatenate values of an object

Tags: javascript, redux, reselect

The selector is as follows:

```
export const findCustomer = createSelector(
  state => state.customers.active,
  users => users.find(user => user.my_property === true)
);
```

It'll return one object:

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "post_code": "zzzzz",
  "category" : "abc",
}
```

What I'm trying to return from this selector in one go is just concatenated 2 values (both are always strings), eg postcode + category

the end output should be a string: 'zzzzzabc'

I know how to do it after I extract the object in a component, but I'd like to do it in the selector itself. Is it possible?

Comment: `I know how to do it after I extract the object in a component` Then do whatever that is in the resultFunc of the createSelector call - i.e. the last function argument that you pass in.

Comment: Thanks @Adam but not sure how to structure it inside a selector. Normally, I'd destructure the values and then concatenate them.

Comment: `Normally, I'd destructure the values and then concatenate them`. Yep. Do that. The line that starts with `users => users.find` is just a function. Put your logic in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to something like this:

```
export const findCustomer = createSelector(
   state => state.customers.active,
   users => { 
    const { post_code, category } = users.find(user => user.my_property === true)
    return post_code + category
   });
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I was overcomplicating selectors